# Construction of Lagrange dual function for optimization problems

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, duality-theorems

Suppose we have the optimization problem in standard form:

minimize$ f_0(x)$

subject to

$f_i(x)\le 0,i=1,..,m$

$h_i(x)= 0,i=1,..,p$

And we indicate $dom \ f_0=dom \ f_i=dom \ h_i =D$. Whereas the feasible set is $F \subset D$. $p^*$ is instead the value of the minimum.

The theory of duality proceeds definining the lagrangian $L(x,\lambda,\nu):$

$L(x,\lambda,\nu)=f_0(x) + \sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i f_i(x)+\sum_{i=1}^p \nu_ih_i(x)$

and the function:

$g(\lambda,\nu)=\inf_{x \in D}L(x,\lambda,\nu)$

Now one central observation is that in this way:

$p^* \ge g(\lambda,\nu)$ if $\lambda \ge 0 \ [1]$

And this is useful because:

1- It is a variational estimate of the minimum.

2- $g$ is concave even if the $f$ are not.

My question is this. If we define the modified $g$ with $\tilde g$:

$\tilde g(\lambda,\nu)=\inf_{x \in F}L(x,\lambda,\nu)$

still I think we would have:

$p^* \ge \tilde g(\lambda,\nu) \ge g(\lambda,\nu), \lambda \ge 0$

and we would have therefore a stronger bound on the minimum.

Why the theory than proceeds with using $g$ rather than $\tilde g$. What is the reason ?

Comment: What leads you to believe that $p^{*} \geq \tilde{g}(\lambda,\nu)$?

Comment: Because $\tilde g(\lambda,\nu) \le L(x,\lambda,\nu) = f_0(x) +\sum_i \lambda_i f_i(x) \le f_0(x)$ for every $x \in F$ and $\lambda \ge 0$. Than taking the minimum over $x \in F$ we have the inequality. It is the same argument that applies to $g$. Am I wrong ?

Comment: and if you could compute $\tilde{g}(\lambda,\nu)$, what would $\tilde{g}(0,0)$ give you?

Comment: So $\tilde g(0,0)$ would be equal to $p^*$ whereas $g(0,0)$ a priori can be lower since we are minimizing over points $x$ which could not be feasible.

Comment: Do you want to say that $\tilde g$ would be too difficult to compute/estimate to be useful since it brings with him too much information of the primal problem ?

Comment: So for this $\tilde g$ essentially we would have that $max \tilde g(\lambda,\nu),\lambda \ge 0$ would be indeed $p^*$ (strong duality) and the maximum would be obtained at $0,0$

Comment: So summarizing, the main idea is that one expects the dual problem rising from $\tilde g$ to be as complicated or even more complicated than the primal problem and therefore one would not proceed in this direction. Instead minimizing over the entire $D$, since it is an unconstrained minimization and since strong duality for $g$ is in this case a non-trivial thing, one could expect to solve a simpler problem... Am I understanding well the philosophy behind the definitions ?